# Why does HTTPBuilder throw "HttpResponseException: Bad Request"?

Tags: groovy, spock, httpbuilder, web-api-testing

**Http-builder: 0.7.1 |
Language: Groovy |
Framework: Spock**

**Testing Code**

```
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import spock.lang.Specification

/**
 * Created by Long Nguyen on 4/11/2017.
 *
 * Chatwork api documentation: http://developer.chatwork.com/ja/index.html
 */
class ChatworkApiSpec extends Specification {
    // https://api.chatwork.com/v2/contacts
    def apiRoot = "http://api.chatwork.com/v2"
    def contactsPath = "/contacts"
    def apiToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx"
    def http = new HTTPBuilder(apiRoot)

    /**
     * Endpoint: /contacts
     * You can access the list of users who are in contact with you.
     */
    def "Get your contact list"() {
        when:
        def response = http.get(path: contactsPath, headers: ["X-ChatWorkToken": apiToken])
        def responseData = response.responseData
        then:
        println responseData
    }
}
```

It always throws below exception. I don't know what i  was wrong with setting headers.

(Of course this api works for me when I use Postman)

**Message:**

```
groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException: Bad Request

    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.defaultFailureHandler(HTTPBuilder.java:652)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:508)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.get(HTTPBuilder.java:292)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.get(HTTPBuilder.java:262)
    at testcase.ChatworkApiSpec.Get your contact list(ChatworkApiSpec.groovy:24)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry my bad question. I release that my root link also included path in it.

Replace:

```
def apiRoot = "http://api.chatwork.com/v2"
def contactsPath = "/contacts"
```

by

```
def apiRoot = "http://api.chatwork.com"
def contactsPath = "/v2/contacts"
```

can resolve this problem.

Comment: As an author, you can always delete a question. And this is what I recommend you to do.

Comment: Maybe someone will have same problem like me, i think it will help alot

Comment: Well, then you should have adjusted the title to the actual problem. I have just done that for you. The problem is not about setting headers as you said. As soon as you have enough reputation to do so, please accept your own answer in order to close the question. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @kriegaex: I will accept my answer after 6 hours. "You can accept your own answer in 6 hours"